# Problems with Regex and Java: Words may contain only letters and hyphens (-) and must begin with a letter

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I've been trying to look into this for ages now and really struggling, using Java and Regex. I am trying to create a regular Expression that matches these criteria:
Words may contain only letters and hyphens (-) and must begin with a letter. No numbers.

My Java code looks as follows:

```
String test="^[a-zA-Z][^\\\\0-9]*[\\-]*[a-zA-Z]*";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(test,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(textInputWord.getText());
if(m.find()){
    String temp = textInputWord.getText();
    wordArrayList.add(temp);
    labelMainText.setText("Word " + textInputWord.getText() + " was added to the ArrayList.");
}else{
    labelMainText.setText("The string " + textInputWord.getText() + " was not added to the list as it is not a valid word.");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `^[a-z][a-z-]*$` if you're using `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`.

Answer (score 2):

The instruction "No numbers" is superfluous, because it already says it can contain only letters and hyphens.

Assuming by letter you mean a normal `A` to `Z`, and assuming that you are still using `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`:

Starts with a letter: `^[a-z]`
Followed by any sequence of letters and hyphens: `[a-z-]*`
In combination: `^[a-z][a-z-]*$`

If you use [`m.matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) instead of [`m.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()), then it is even simpler:

```
[a-z][a-z-]*
```

Comment: Instead of `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` as a second argument, just prefix regex with [`(?i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE), then the regex is self-contained. Alternatively, give regex as `\p{Alpha}[\p{Alpha}-]*`. Then you could prefix [`(?U)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) for unicode letters, though if you want that, [`\p{L}[\p{L}-]*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#unicode) would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
//starting with one or more letters then can contain as many as you want with - included
[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z-]*
```

Comment: This regex does not match the whole word (from start to end).

Comment: The `+` is unnecessary. It'll match the same without it.

Comment: @Sunil B N _Words may contain only letters and hyphens (-) and must begin with a letter._ Your regex however matches the word `1abc-def` (not the whole word of course)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much easier than what you're doing:

```
String test = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\-]*";
```

However that will only work for ASCII A-Z not for words with accents and diacritics.

Comment: No need to escape `-` if first or last in the character class. Doesn't hurt though.

Answer (score 0):

```
String test="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\-]*";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(test);
Matcher m = p.matcher(textInputWord.getText());

if(m.find()){
    String temp = textInputWord.getText();
    wordArrayList.add(temp);
    labelMainText.setText("Word " + textInputWord.getText() + " was added to the ArrayList.");
}else{
    labelMainText.setText("The string " + textInputWord.getText() + " was not added to the list as it is not a valid word.");
}
```